# Deployment Issues with Activiti Engine

Tags: java, activiti

I am trying to start a process in `Alfresco Activiti` externally using a standalone java program. My java program and `.bpmn20.xml` reside on `Eclipse IDE`. On executing the java program, the process doesn’t get deployed. Any pointers on why this is happening ?

The logs in eclipse show a h2 database connection been made to `jdbc\:h2\:mem:activiti.`

I have configured my database properties(within activiti-app.properties) to `datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/activiti`

Is this the reason why my process isn’t getting deployed ? If yes…how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you share the Java code you are using to deploy the process? You must explicitly do this in your code, it will not be discovered automatically.

Comment: ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration().buildProcessEngine();
RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
repositoryService.createDeployment().addClasspathResource("diagram/TestingThruActiviti.bpmn20.xml").deploy();
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("TestingThruActiviti");

Comment: public class TestingABC 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
     ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration().buildProcessEngine();
     RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
     RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
            repositoryService.createDeployment().addClasspathResource("diagram/TestingThruActiviti.bpmn20.xml").deploy();
     ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("TestingThruActiviti");  
 }
}

Comment: can you post the error or exception you are getting?. i am sharing a [link](http://programmingoverflow14.blogspot.in/2016/01/jump-start-with-activiti-bpm-along-with.html) where it's working example is given

Comment: Rather than post the code as a comment where it is not readable, it would be better if you updated the original question to include it inside a formatted block, with some context